# Any open subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ contains $U_n(K)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

My setting is the $p$-adic field. $K$ (finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$.) Proposition [2.1.18](http://users.ictp.it/%7Epub_off/lectures/lns021/Wedhorn/Wedhorn.pdf) seems to claim that

> Any open subgroup of $GL_n(K)$. contains $U_n(K)$ the unipotent upper triangular matrices.

Is this true? If so, is there a reference?

Comment: This is true if the subgroup is normal. This not true in general: e.g. take a congruence subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, is there a reference for the normal case?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but the proof is short: You can conjugate any unipotent upper triangular matrix by a diagonal matrix (with $i$th diagonal entry $p^{ni}$, say) to obtain a matrix which is congruent to $1$ modulo an arbitrarily high power of $p$, hence in an arbitrary open neighborhood of the identity.